# FXMLLoader how to access the components by FXID?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying to figure out how to work with JavaFx.
I built the application interface in Scene Builder. But I can not get access to the component, since all loaded into the Parent.

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
```

If I change "Parent" on "Pane" I can get access to the getChildren(), but it is not clear how to get control if i know fx:id...

The question is even simpler. I added Label or TextField in Scene Builder. How do I change it's text from the code if I know the fx:id?

I am in despair.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should create a controller class for your FXML document, in which you can perform any functionality you need to perform involving the UI components. You can annotate fields in that class with `@FXML` and they will be populated by the `FXMLLoader`, matching the `fx:id` attribute to the field name.

Work through the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm) for more details, and have a look at the [Introduction to FXML documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers).

Simple example:

Sample.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="SampleController">
    <Label fx:id="countLabel"/>
    <Button fx:id="incrementButton" text="Increment" onAction="#increment"/>
</VBox>
```

SampleController.java:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;


public class SampleController {

    private int count = 0 ;

    @FXML
    private Label countLabel ;

    @FXML
    private void increment() {
        count++;
        countLabel.setText("Count: "+count);
    }
}
```

SampleMain.java:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SampleMain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml")), 250, 75);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I call `increment()`? If I call it in SampleMain using a reference to the controller, the program crashes

Answer (score 14):

[FXMLLoader.getNamespace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getNamespace()) can be used, this is a map of named components.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
TextField foo = (TextField)loader.getNamespace().get("exampleFxId");
```

Comment: That's interesting: I've been working with FX8 on an almost-daily basis since the first prerelease, and I never saw this approach before. I think the standard approach of using a controller class is better as it provides a clean separation of concerns an encourages a better overall design, but I can see this might have some uses in some cases.

Comment: I agree I only use controllers too, just a useful hook in the API