# How can I load a specific container from an FXML document?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml, fxmlloader

I am building application which has different interfaces. I have decided to use the JavaFX for this and I wanted to know if I could have multiple containers saved in the FXML document and when using the the FXML Loader, pick a specific container by the id (i.e., `fx:id`).

I have recently come to know that several people grouped against me and make question duplicate. I will now state my defence and prove this is not duplicate.

What that question doesn't answer mine is the fact that I want to set fx:id for parent itself and use the fxmlloader to load parent on basis of id. Ok?

Comment: What do you mean with container? Do you mean the controller?

Comment: @fireandfuel For example, Anchor Pane. Or Grid Pane. Like those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FXMLLoader how to access the components by FXID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962788/fxmlloader-how-to-access-the-components-by-fxid)

Comment: @yeedle yup, it seems very similar. However I think he/she/they want to ask how to load the parent itself with an id.

Comment: @RahulSrinath **YES** you get me! That is what I want. btw I am a "he"

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using the FXML loader's `getNamespace` method.

(code from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962824/4240010), but see comments):

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
TextField foo = (TextField)loader.getNamespace().get("exampleFxId");
```

A better approach is to have separate fxml files for all your needs and then load each one as needed with the `FXMLLoader.load()` method.

Comment: I agree with that Rahul fellow, I am looking for loading parent with fx:id